# Jquery each cannot call methods

Tags: jquery

So far i have the code below:

```
$('.pagination').each(function(){
    var paginationWidth = $(this).width();
    var pixelOffset = '-' + paginationWidth + 'px';
    console.log(paginationWidth.css('margin-left', pixelOffset ));
});
```

Console log shows "Object 57 has no method 'css'", the number being the width. Why is this the case on an each element? If its not an array why can't .css() be called upon each of said elements?

Comment: `var paginationWidth = $(this).width();` which is not a jquery object (just a number). Try `$(this).css('margin-left', pixelOffset )`

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is nothing to do with the `each` loop. The `.width()` jQuery method returns a value, and you're then trying to set a CSS property of that value. The $(this) inside your each loop is still the object.

Your last line wants to be this instead.

```
$(this).css('margin-left', pixelOffset )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.pagination').each(function(){
    var page=$(this);
    var paginationWidth = page.width();
    var pixelOffset = '-' + paginationWidth + 'px';
    console.log(page.css('margin-left', pixelOffset ));
});
```

`$(this).width()` is not returns an object.It returns an integer number which representing it's width.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is $(this)... literally if you excuse the joke... See below.

```
('.pagination').each(function(){
   var paginationWidth = $(this).width();
   var pixelOffset = '-' + paginationWidth + 'px';
   console.log($(this).css('margin-left', pixelOffset ));
);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works like

$(selector).function/event(.....

but paginationWidth is not a selector. selectors are objects to be selected.

Better to use

```
$('any-selector-to apply-margin-left').css('margin-left', pixelOffset );
```